# Methods that don't change a variable's value need to be synchronized if they accessed the variable

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized, scjp

From page 231 of OCP Java SE 6 Programmer Practice Exams, question 56:

```
public class Buffalo {
    protected int y;
    public int getY() { return y; }
    public void setY(int newY) { y = newY; }
}
```

Which methods need to be synchronized to make the class thread safe?

And the book says that the correct answer is - all of them:

> Even methods that don't change a variable's value need to be
>   synchronized if they accessed the variable.

Why I need to synchronize `getY()`?

It's not changing the state, so it can't cause any synchronization problems, isn't it?

Comment: If another thread changes the variable the getY() method needs to b e synchronized to that change in another thread.

Comment: Thread1 - changes y using setY()  Thread2 - access y using getY() needs to be able to see change that Thread1 made.